# Create a user profile in unix

Tags: unix

On a unix server, I need always do sudo su - superusername Due to this no two or more people can work simultaneously on a process. I need to remove this overhead by removing the sudo step. Every user will have its own profile and they will no more share the same environment by doing sudo. Kindly help how can I create a user with same privileges as of superusername.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these command to do that but it is not a good idea to give root priveledge to normal user

```
$ sudo useradd -ou 0 -g 0 username
```

**Little Extra** : This to set password to the new user you have created

```
$ sudo passwd username
```